# Why does [pdf]latex not produce a page when nothing is in the body?

Tags: blank-page

Having a blank PDF file may be useful for a certain situation that I don't know.

Neither

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

nor

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

produce a page when each of them is compiled using either `pdflatex` or `latex`.

Note: `[pdf]latex` can produce a blank single-page PDF with the following trick:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\  
\end{document}
```

### Questions

Why does `[pdf]latex` not produce a blank single-page PDF when nothing is the input file body?

Comment: a general rule: nothing in the body, no output

Comment: Put `\leavevmode` or something inside to get an empty document.

Comment: @xport `~` is more minimal: it's a non-breaking space.

Comment: @Seamus: It works. Excellent optimizer. :-)

Comment: The shortest named macro might be `\null`. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TeX works (conceptually) by adding material to a 'scroll', then cutting pages from this. Until you add *something*, there is no scroll to cut material off. As the comments have made clear, there are several ways to force printing a blank page by adding something invisible to the 'scroll'. However, that is very different from expecting blank pages. I wonder how you would differentiate between the case you outline and what happens after the last page of an normal (text-containing) document.